# What is the difference between sklearn's transform() and predict() methods?

Tags: scikit-learn

The difference between `fit()` and the above mentioned two methods is very distinct. `fit` is present in all classes of sklearn and fits an object's internal variables according to the class, be it a training model class or a preprocessor one.

The difference between `transform()` and `predict()`, however, seems to be a little vague. One general rule I have seen being thrown around is that - `predict()` belongs to a supervised learning class and `transform()` belongs to an unsupervised learning class.

Nevertheless, I have found some exceptions to this general rule. K-Means (an unsupervised algorithm) and PLSRegression (a supervised one) are two classes that have *both* of these methods. I went through the K-Means documentation and I've understood what the two different methods return; but the implementations of these two interfaces don't seem VERY concretely defined in the documentation.

Like `fit()`, `transform()` can mean different things depending upon context. For a preprocessing class, `fit()` calculates the mean of the dataset, for example and `transform` applies it. For a training class, `fit()` acts differently and trains the model.

`predict()` is still very self explanatory and I have only included it in the question because the different usages of `transform()` seems only explainable with `predict()` as a point of comparison.

After having gone through a multitude of questions, parts of the documentation including the development manual, the glossary, and little parts of the Hands-on ML Book, this is the conclusion I have arrived at -
It seems as if these interfaces are not meant to have a clear cut definition and are meant to be flexible with every class that is written.

Is this correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`predict` methods take the input features and return something that is *qualitatively* different, i.e. labels `y` (in supervised settings) or cluster memberships (in most clustering settings).

`transform`, on the other hand, as its name already implies, returns something that is qualitatively *similar* to its input but expressed in a different *form*, i.e. scaled features, PCA features etc. And as a rule, they are usually accompanied with a respective `inverse_transform` method to return the input to its original form (while arguably we cannot imagine an `inverse_predict` method, to go from labels or cluster memberships to features).

This difference is readily apparent in cases such as the ones you mention, where both `predict` and `transform` methods are available; in kmeans, for example, `predict(X)` will return cluster memberships, but `transform(X)` will return a transformation (i.e. different version) `X_new` of the input features.

Comment: That makes a lot of things clear, thanks! As an addendum could also please explain the difference in the PLSRegression's transform and predict methods?

Comment: @RajdeepBiswas I'm not at all familiar with what PLSRegression actually does, so I wouldn't like to risk saying things that might not hold. But arguably you get the whole point.

Comment: @RajdeepBiswas in PLSRegression, if you use ```transform(X)```  you will get the latent variables scores; if you use ```predict(X)```you will have the predictions of your model.

Comment: *Qualitatively different* and *qualitatively similar* are rather vague concepts, although very intuitive and accessible to beginners. I suppose, a more rigorous distinction between `transform` and `predict` can be made by their semantics in the context of pipelines and model compositions. I wonder if you could expand your answer to shed light on this aspect too, if you see what I mean and happen to have a clear understanding of it?